# CSS3 Animation reverts back to 0 opacity at end

Tags: css, animation

I'm adding an animation to some elements when the user clicks something. By default the elements are at 0 opacity and go to 1 opacity when the animation is added.

The problem: they revert back to 0 opacity after the animation is complete.

I added `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` as suggested by every related answer but it still doesn't work.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/9bs9g3uw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the last keyframe to `100%` instead of `50%`, only then it will override the initial `.element {opacity: 0}` rule:

```
100% {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bs9g3uw/1/)